# How to integrate Tapku with CalDAV service?

Tags: iphone, ipad, calendar, caldav, tapku

I am developing a calendar application using Tapku library. I need to connect Tapku calendar with a CalDAV server.

Does anyone know how to configure Tapku calendar with CalDAV service or any other iOS calendar library where I can connect with CalDAV server?

At least does anyone know how to implement a CalDav iOS calendar? Because there are some apps out there which is connected to a calendar server. Also I cannot use default iOS calendar since my requirement is to show all the calendar data within my app.

Answer (score 1):

I feel you can use one of the C or C++ or Objective C library mentioned in the link below.

http://caldav.calconnect.org/implementations/librariestools.html

As far as I could guess the library in the following link should be a good bet. You'd might need to do some work to get it working on iOS. I've not used this library but as I see this library supports the standard CalDav format and are being used in other projects. Hence,this is your best bet.

http://sope.opengroupware.org/en/sope_ical/index.html

*Disclaimer: I've not used this library.*